# Laravel 5.4 - Error Message Without Form Validation

Tags: php, laravel

Want to know if I can use the validation error message on Laravel 5.4 with my custom error message that does not include a form validation.

I am making a validation on view user profile that is to make sure only the owner of the id can view the user profile using `Gate`.

Do I need to create the instance of `Validator` and do something like on the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#after-validation-hook).

Below are the example of my codes,

**UserController.php**

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    if (\Gate::denies('showUser', $user)) {
        return redirect()->back()
        ->with('status', 'Invalid Access to other User Profile');
        // how to use instead ->withErrors($message); ?
    }

    return view('profiles.update', compact('user'));
}
```

**messages.blade.php**

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

        <ol>

        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)  

                <li>{{ $error }}</li>           

        @endforeach

        </ol> 

    </div>
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class='alert alert-success'>
        {!! session('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif

@if(session('status'))
    <div class='alert alert-danger'>
        {!! session('status') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: tried [flash message](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data) yet?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully, this helps.

```
public function show(User $user, MessageBag $message_bag)
{
    if (\Gate::denies('showUser', $user)) {
        $message_bag->add('token', 'This is the error message');
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($message_bag);
    }

    return view('profiles.update', compact('user'));
}
```